# How to get the value of span tag based on css class in jquery?

Tags: jquery, text, html

How to get the value of span tag based on css class in jquery?

```
<span class="page-numbers current">3</span>
```

I used

```
var pageno = $(".page-numbers current").val();
  alert(pageno);
```

it doesnt seem to work.any suggestion..

EDIT:i am using jquery pagination plugin for pagination... for first page `1` and `prev` are assigned css class `class="page-numbers current`

```
<span class="page-numbers current prev">Prev</span>
<span class="page-numbers current">1</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

".page-numbers" and "current" are 2 different css classes.

Your jQuery expects "current" to be inside of ".page-numbers".

Also use text() for non-input elements.

This should work

```
alert($(".page-numbers").text());
```

EDIT: Furthermore, current hasn't got a class (.) or id (#) prefix which means it's looking for an element "current", which doesn't exist. Use #current or .current

Comment: i want to get current page number

Comment: If class="current" only appears on one element, simply use $(".current").text()

Comment: for first page i get `prev1` and for the last page i get `3next` all highlighted

Answer (score 1):

```
var pageno = $(".page-numbers.current").text();
  alert(pageno);
```

see second example [class-selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: for first page i get `prev1` and for the last page i get `3next` all highlighted

Comment: @bala - I don't understand... there's something you have not explained in your html structure... can you edit your post with more detail of the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I assume only the **current** page was the class `.current` so grab it using only that selector.

Grab it using jQuery **[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** like this:

```
// do notice that a . was added to class .current!
var pageno = $(".current").html();
alert(pageno);
```

You were trying to capture the `val` that exists in fields like input.

```
// on a field like this what you were doing would work perfectly
<input type='text' val='12' />
```